# Using .htaccess to prevent direct URL access to all BUT the index file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a .htaccess file intended to limit access to a reserved folder which stores PHP code necessary for my domain. For brevity, let's call this folder "PHP" and my domain "example.com"; in other words, the URL to this folder would be:

```
https://www.example.com/PHP/
```

Obviously, I don't want users to galivant through this folder, so it seems it would be common-sense to prevent all access to the folder. There's one caveat, though: one file in the folder *can and will* be accessed by the users on my domain --- the index file (as this file runs all the other files in this reserved folder via PHP's `fopen()` function).

As such, I need to use a RewriteRule that prevents this URL...

```
https://www.example.com/PHP/someRandomPHPFile.php
```

...but not these URLs:

```
https://www.example.com/PHP/
https://www.example.com/PHP/index.php
```

---

Currently, I have this in my .htaccess file in the PHP folder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://%{HTTP_HOST} [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://%{HTTP_HOST}.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule !^(.*)/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/PHP/ [L,R=301,NE]
```

...but this is not redirecting correctly, as every time it redirects to the index it gives me a "Hmmm...can’t reach this page" screen (including the index file when a form submits and redirects to it). I think the issue lies in that it is also redirecting when the index file is accessed via a URL. However, due to my inexperience with .htaccess files and RewriteRules, I'm not sure how to resolve this issue.

I am trying to redirect any URL that targets files in the reserved folder --- **outside** of the index file --- back to the index, since the index file has checks ingrained into it to handle illicit and/or non-standard form-submission access for all the other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shouldn’t be matching the referer. You should be matching on the URL.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/PHP/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PHP/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/PHP/index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /PHP/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This does seem to work, but PHP's `fopen()` function is not working with this solution (which is what I am using to allow the index file to utilize the other files in the PHP folder); is that expected to happen? Is there a way to modify these conditions to allow `fopen()` to access the PHP folder but not the user via "punching in" the URL?

Comment: You should use the path with `fopen()` instead of a URL. You can do `fopen("/path/to/PHP/file.php")`.